# To Know The Source Code Of a Captcha from a particular website

Tags: captcha

"https://services.gst.gov.in/services/captcha?rnd=". My question is how can I able to create the same captcha image and what will be it's source code with css in PHP or other language?

Comment: This question is quite impossible to answer for a good number of reasons, most important of which is that the site appears to be down, you also ask "the same captcha image", you mean **the exact image it currently shows you**? I would assume you can't or the captch isn't any good. There should be numerous captcha solutions available, may I ask why you require this particular captch (or image....?)

Comment: If they have a proprietary solution, you can't see or get the source code from that website. You're probably best off picking an existing captcha solution for your own website.